# Using an OnnxTensor value in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, onnxruntime

I'm using onnxruntime-android within a Kotlin app, but am having trouble with using the result from an inference.

I can create arrays in Kotlin to construct the model and run inference, but when I get the result back as in

```
val result = ortSession.run(inputs)
```

the model outputs the result as a 2D tensor with one element

```
val probArray = result[0].value -> (this is a float[][])
```

To get the float I have to index into the array

```
val probability = probArray[0][0]
```

however this generates a compile time error.  I need a way to cast `probability` into something Kotlin can use such as an `Array<Array<Float>>` but when I try to run

```
val probArray = result[0].value as Array<Array<Float>>
```

I get a runtime error for the cast

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: float[][] cannot be cast to java.lang.Float[][]
```

I understand the error, but cannot figure out a way to simply access the value inside `probArray`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was able to get this working with

```
val probArray = result[0].value as Array<FloatArray>
val probability = probArray[0][0]
```